# Android- Get a random number each time and call the value in another class

Tags: java, android

I wanted the ID to change 5 times when I click the button and not just a number repeated 5 times each time I click the button

I already tried to put the variable ID in onCreate, even outside, but it does not keep repeating the same number. (I know that onCreate happens only once when the app is started)

And I also wanted to know how I get the ID value in other classes, like getID

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        int ID = new Random().nextInt(10879) + 4;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("%s", ID), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // call the getID
            getID();
        }
    }

    public void getID() {
        // get the value ID here
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="253dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> ```
````

Comment: Nice StackOverflow question ID 

Comment: @Gene Could be nicer.

Comment: @Manuel: Ah, it seems, that the answer below has the ID 66666666.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. But if u want to get different ID for 5 times when you click the button, then you should change the value of ID in the for loop.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ID++;  // Change the value of ID here
    
    // Display your ID here
}
```

Then for the getting of ID in other class, you should pass the ID value to the getID class.

For example:

```
public void getID(int ID) {
    // Then you can use the value of ID
}
```

Then to call the getID class:

```
getID(ID);
```

Edited:

If you are trying to get the ID form other activity, then you should be using intend to pass the value:

```
Intend intend = new Intend(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intend.putExtra("ID", ID);
```

Then getting the ID in next activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if (bundle.getInt("ID")!= null) {
    ID = bundle.getInt("ID");
}
```

Credit: Sujit

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the second part of your answer is what he wants. I believe he wants to access the id from this activity in another activity, in which case he has to pass the id as an extra (`putExtra()` & `getExtra()`) while starting a new activity.

Comment: Changing the value in the loop worked, but now, when I go to getID, it takes the NEW value that was generated, I wanted to take the value and send it to getID

it sends the value, but it does so

value: 100
getID: 101

Loop

value: 102
getID: 103

how I wish:

value: 100
getID: 100

Loop

value 101
getID: 101

I hope I was a little clear this time, and I thank you for your help

Comment: it worked for me like that 

when the value entered getID I used "ID--;

Comment: @ChickChuck2 The you can use another variables llike `newID` to store the new value, when calling the `getID()` you can use the old value `ID`